# Are there microwaves to heat baby food at Brussels airport?

Tags: airports, food-and-drink, children, bru

I've a friend traveling with kids, passing through Brussels. He will need to feed a baby and was wondering if there was any facility to warm up his food at Zaventem.

@chx answer is very helpful, but I would also appreciate some first hand experience.

These type of website claims, sometimes, don't translate into usable equipment. And I don't mean it's not true, but simply - there used to be microwaves but got broken, became unusable, stores redesigned etc.

Comment: I can't imagine that a restaurant or cafe whose _capability to heat food_ breaks down would not get it fixed within hours or days, out of economic self-interest. Do you seriously imagine a major international airport would be filled with restaurants all boarded up with "CLOSED, our microwave is broken" signs?

Comment: @Henning Even in airports, which are not generally known for their Michelin-rate cuisine, I would not expect a restaurant’s ability to heat food to rely solely on a microwave.

Comment: Yes, people who care about food don't consider microwaves as a primary heating devce.  I don't use them for food at all; I use them to disinfect sponges.  Least, hotspots are a huge risk when feeding a person of reduced capacity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you're assuming it's the microwave in the kitchen restaurant. I read it as public microwaves in the client service area. It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 31):

[Babies and small children at the airport](https://www.brusselsairport.be/en/passengers/at-the-airport/special-care-travels/travellig-with-children-overview/travelling-with-babies-and-small-children)

> Did you bring your own baby food to the airport? You can have it heated in all restaurants at the airport. Our staff are happy to be of assistance. Microwave ovens are available in most of the airport restaurants.

Comment: I don't remember seeing any such thing in Brussels, but I remember a sign stating "WE HAVE MICROWAVES" at a food court in Seville, Spain — and, indeed, the food court had public-access microwaves. I know that's quite some ways away, but it _is_ the EU. So at least maybe we can agree that it's a _possibility_?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93690/discussion-on-answer-by-chx-are-there-microwaves-to-heat-baby-food-at-brussels-a).

Answer (score 3):

Not Brussels airport specific - but in general, when travelling or eating out, some places won't heat up baby milk/food in a microwave (the usual excuse is legal liability about "preparing food"). An alternative is to ask for a large cup of boiled water instead, and place the baby food in there to warm up. Every eatery can provide hot water, it's the same as providing a cup of tea.